# the objective function $\|F\|_F^2$ is quasiconvex in the optimization?why?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control

I have read a paper, but I can not understand one optimization thoroughly.Generally, Frobenius norm of one matrix, $\|F\|_F^2$, as the objective function is convex, so we can resolve it not using the bisection method. Within the paper, the authour say that under the given constraint,  $\|F\|_F^2$ is quasiconvex, it should be resolved using the bisection method , why?

Note that, the matrix $F$ is the variable.

the paper comes from http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6555249&queryText%3DWorst-Case+Robust+Masked+Beamforming+for.

The picture is a simplified description of it.[image: description of the problem]